# Difference between new inflation and chaotic inflation

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

I'm trying to understand the difference between new inflation and Linde's chaotic inflation. From what I understand, according to the old inflation, during inflation empty space remains empty, so its energy density does not change.
The universe with a constant energy density expands exponentially, thus we
have inflation *in* the false vacuum. This expansion makes the universe very
big and very flat, *after* which the false vacuum decays.
In new inflation, inflation may begin either in
the false vacuum, or in an unstable state at the top of the effective potential.
Then the inflaton field $φ$ slowly rolls down to the minimum of its effective
potential.
Is the rolling of this inflaton field to the true vacuum what we call inflation?

I further am confused about chaotic inflation. It says that inflation may happen with any potential. What, however, is the difference in terms of the inflaton field between new and chaotic inflation? [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/116226/342569) answer says that chaotic inflation is chaotic in terms of the initial conditions. What are the initial conditions for new inflation then?